# REACTJS - Assign a <Tag> to a variable?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I've been questioning myself if its possible to assign a Tag to a Variable without the compiler going ham.

Example:

```
 let component = '<div>';
 let component2 = '</div>';
```

Results in an Output of `<div>` and not the displayed `<div>`.

This is the desired result:

```
 let component = <div>;
 let component2 = </div>;
```

Here the joke begins. When assigned like this, the compiler is throwing an error because the tag is not enclosed.

```
 let component = <div/>;
```

This on the other hand works, as its just a component-assignment.

Now is it somehow possible to assign a mere `<div>` to a variable that can be swapped out with for example a `<p>` ?

Comment: React doesn't have a concept of tags (well, ReactDOM might). Are you trying to change a `div` to a `p`?

Comment: Ok, I will bite. Why?

Comment: You can do `const Tag = 'div'` and then in your components `<Tag>asd</Tag>`. You can either assign a React component to the variable, or a HTML DOM node's name which will be rendered as an element. Just make sure the variable name starts with a capital letter so the JSX compiler (babel, probably) is happy.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no tags in react. JSX that you are using is transformed into `createElement` calls. Next two pieces of code are equivalent.

```js
<div>
  <p>1234</p>
</div>;

createElement("div", null, createElement("p", null, "1234"));
```

If you somehow want to "swap" one element for another you can look closely to what is happening when you transform JSX to plain JavaScript. You pass element name as a string and you for sure can place strings into variables. So, if we want to swap "div" to "p" best way would be to do this:

```js
function DivThatSwapsToParagraph() {
  let [Tag, setTag] = useState("div");

  return createElement(
    Tag,
    null,
    createElement(
      "button",
      {
        onClick() {
          setTag(Tag === "div" ? "p" : "div");
        },
      },
      "Swap"
    )
  );
}
```

Notice that I used capital letter in `Tag`. It is mandatory if you will use JSX, because lowercase first letter indicates built-in elements (what you call tags) and are quoted after transformation. If you do `<tag/>` it will be transformed as `createElement('tag')`. With upper cased variable you can use your `Tag` variable as a compoent, so code above in JSX form would look like this:

```js
function DivThatSwapsToParagraph() {
  let [Tag, setTag] = useState("div");

  return (
    <Tag>
      <button
        onClick={function onClick() {
          setTag(Tag === "div" ? "p" : "div");
        }}
      >
        Swap
      </button>
    </Tag>
  );
}
```

Here is a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Lkfpromn/) for you to play with.

Please note, that in many cases that would be bad pattern, so use with caution.

Answer (score 2):

Any HTML you enter in React is actually interpreted as JSX.

*From **[React Docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/introducing-jsx.html)**:*

*Babel compiles JSX down to React.createElement() calls.*

**These two examples are identical:**

```
const element = (
  <h1 className="greeting">
    Hello, world!
  </h1>
);

const element = React.createElement(
  'h1',
  {className: 'greeting'},
  'Hello, world!'
);
```

---

If you are trying to store a single tag as a variable then it's possible but only with elements that are accepted as single tags in **JSX**.

```
const br = <br/>;

export default function App() {
  return <div className="App">Hello{br}World</div>;
}
```

The above code will render a break between **Hello** and **World**.

You can also store divs but they must have an enclosing tag to work properly.

**Example:**

```
const div = <div> Variable Div </div>
```

[Here is a working sandbox.](https://codesandbox.io/s/charming-sea-m1jjo?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark)

You can also set HTML directly from React but you must specify using [dangerouslySetInnerHTML](https://reactjs.org/docs/dom-elements.html#dangerouslysetinnerhtml).